# Sequential square packings

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, recreational-mathematics, packing-problem, tiling

There are various studies for packing sequential squares of size $1$ to $n$. We can try to find the smallest square they will pack into, as in [tightly packed squares](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TightlyPackedSquares/). We can find the smallest square they will fit into, [A005842](https://oeis.org/search?q=A005842&language=english&go=Search). We can find an [optimal stacking](https://erich-friedman.github.io/mathmagic/1099.html) for them.

Adam Ponting found an efficient packing for squares of size $1$ to $(2 n+1)^2$, as seen in his article [square packing](http://www.adamponting.com/square-packing/). I expanded that for [Ponting Square Packing](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PontingSquarePacking/). In the below, an offset is used on his method to pack squares of size 32 to 200. A value of 31 can be subtracted from all sizes for a packing of squares 1 to 169.

[image: Ponting packing 32-200]

So, what is a square packing?  For the purposes of this article, I'll define it as follows:

1. Up to 4 squares can have 2 fully exposed edges. All other squares must have 2 or more edges fully covered and a third at least partially covered.
2. No holes are allowed in the packing.

Ponting mentions only finding packings for an odd square number of sequential squares.  I took a look at order-4 and sizes representable in a 4x4 matrix and found 8 solutions. The second one has squares with sizes {{11, 8, 15,6},{7,12,5,16},{9,4,13,2},{3,10,1,14}}.

[image: even square packings]

I haven't been able to find solutions with a 6x6 or higher even matrix. Can anyone find those, or other square packings of sequential squares?